# How to modify the sequence of a GenBank record?

Tags: python, sequence, biopython, genome

What I would like to do is to make all non putative sequences of a GenBank record in lowercase in the genome file.

So far, I managed to obtain the start and end location of the proteins in the gbk.
From there I do the following:

```
start = feature.location.nofuzzy_start
end = feature.location.nofuzzy_end
gb_record.seq[start:end]
```

Now I have the start and end location of the sequence in the genome. But how do I modify the genome file? `gb_record.seq[start:end].lower()` or something similar did not do the trick.

When I assign `gb_record.seq = gb_record.seq[start:end].lower`, it obviously goes wrong as I replace the genome file. Any ideas?

Comment: Solution:

Found a solution but not really a biopython solution. 
First place the genome.seq file in a genome string file.

    genome = str(gb_record.seq)

Then while going through the gb_record.featers

    start = feature.location.nofuzzy_start
    end = feature.location.nofuzzy_end
    upper = genome[start:end]
    lower = genome[start:end].lower()
    genome = genome.replace(upper,lower)....... Sorry for the formatting, but I cant give the solution myself (not allowed)

Answer (score 1):

`Bio.Seq.Seq` objects have a [`lower()`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Seq.Seq-class.html#lower) method that will do what you're looking for.

Working off your code, you'd get:

```
seq_lower = gb_record.seq.lower()
```

You should then be able to use the `SeqIO` module to write out the lowercase sequences to file.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

with open("example.fasta", 'w') as handle:
    SeqIO.write(lower_records, handle, 'fasta')
```